# Latex how to quote command

Tags: latex

Could you please help me, how to quote command in Latex? for example In my work I describe what "\usepackage{tikz}" does,but it compile me as command and show as an error, not as part of my text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To include code, you can use `\verb` (verbatim). Inside `\verb`, everything is printed as you write it, so you can use no commands. `\verb` is delimited by two identical characters, usually `+` or `|`. Important: these characters can not show up inside the code you want to print.

```
\verb+\usepackage{tikz}+
\verb|\usepackage{tikz}|
```

For larger sections, you can use

```
\begin{verbatim}
...
\end{verbatim}
```

If your code doesn't contain any characters which are treated specially by TeX (i.e. no `\` etc.), you can also use `\texttt{...}` which prints the content in typewriter font.